# How can I use graph-tool to calculate katz centrality for a graph which contain 2 million vertex

Tags: python-3.x, graph-tool

The code is very simple:

```
centrality = graph_tool.centrality.katz(Graph)
```

but there are some warnings：

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:2056: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
return sqrt(add.reduce((x.conj() * x).real, axis=None))
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/graph_tool/centrality/__init__.py:765: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
vprop.fa = vprop.fa / numpy.linalg.norm(vprop.fa)
```

These warnings maybe caused by the size of this graph, how can I deal with it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the normalization step with:

```
centrality = graph_tool.centrality.katz(Graph, norm=False)
```

you can then divide by the maximum value first, when normalizing:

```
centrality.fa /= centrality.fa.max()
centrality.fa /= numpy.linalg.norm(centrality.fa)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but when I run these three line code, there is a another problem:`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide centrality.fa /= centrality.fa.max()`very likely， there are some NaN or zero value. Just ignore it? or we can solve it through some way. thank you.

Comment: Why don't you look inside the array to see what values it has? What is the value of `centrality.fa.max()`?

Comment: `centrality.fa.max() = inf`. Maybe I got some trouble. In order to ensure that the graph is created correctly, I tired two methods: using edge list and `graph_tool.load_graph_from_csv(filePath, directed=False)`, but the result is same with each other.

Comment: If you are seeing inf (without normalization) then maybe the algorithm is failing to converge. Try using smaller values for the parameter ``alpha``.